# ChildAdded with LimitToLast triggers ChildRemoved

Tags: ios, firebase

Regarding Firebase documentation if you limit your query with "toLast" then when a child is added, if you already exceed the value (in my case f.e. 50) then child removed is also triggered because the first child is deleted from the scope.

The following listeners are the ones I have on the code:

```
firebaseReference.queryOrderedByKey().queryLimited(toLast: 50).observe(.childAdded...
firebaseReference.queryOrderedByKey().queryLimited(toLast: 50).observe(.childRemoved...
```

I would like to know if there is some way to differenciate when a child is really deleted or a child is just deleted from the scope.

Thank you so much,
any further information don't hestiate to ask.

Comment: why do you want queryLimit for listeners? `firebaseReference.observe(.childAdded...` 
`firebaseReference.observe(.childRemoved..` is enough right?

Comment: I am doing pagination on a chat, sorry I should have mentioned that.

Comment: Even then it is fine. you can have queryLimit for fetching msgs, not for the listeners. For ex: fetch 50 msg each when you scroll to bottom - this is using queryLimit, and observers for new msg and deleted msg (without query limit)

Comment: The point is that when you do childAdded, this function will return all the values already existing on the DB with the scope you have provide. If you don't limit the scope then it will notify that a child has been added for each element already existing in firebase. This is only the first time.

Comment: but I am doing the same way I said, I don't get any issue as you tell. In my case, I am fetching 10 objects at a time when user scrolls down and reloads the view. I have listeners for child added, changed and deleted and I am getting single object in listener.

Comment: Then should be me that I am not understanding with words. Do you mind write an answer with some demo code? I am really sorry but I don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase does not send along information on why you're receiving the `.childRemoved` event, so there's no way to know it based on that.

The only thing I can quickly think of is adding a `.value` listener for each child, which will then fire with `null` when the child gets deleted.

You'll want to remove the `.value` listener after you receive the `.childRemoved` handler, to not have dangling listeners for each child you've ever seen, so this may become more work than it's worth.

Comment: Since people is talking a lot in the conversations it will be a lot of listeners.

Comment: It should only be as many items as you're currently showing on the screen, so 50 in your sample queries. But agreed that even that is quite some listeners to manage. While technically it's all possible and even quite efficient, the code may not be feasible for your app/use-case.